Jones polynomial for virtual links
So, the KnotTheory package for Mathematica is advertised as working for classical links. But one can construct a PD code for a virtual link as well. Will this package correctly calculate the Jones polynomial from it?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Just to make it clear to other usees, this question as pointed as it can be. The only additional thing that would be helpful would be a couple of PD codes for virtual knots along with some desired outcomes.

With regard to the question: No, I am not aware that it can do this. What I can say because I have recently worked with (virtual) knots and links a lot: KnotTheory is the library of my choice for computing link polynomials. (It is still of interest because it can compute Khovanov homology, but extrapolating from the other code I have seen, it must be, very, very slow.)

The Regina project has far more efficient implementations of the Jones polynomial and of the HOMFLY-PT polynomial. You can use Regina directly from Python or use Mathematica to call into the Python interface. The latter works quite nice for me. However, I don't believe that Regina would accept truely virtual knots. If you post a few PD codes here, then I can try them for you.

@HenrikSchumacher K = PD[
X[30, 3, 31, 2], X[29, 19, 30, 18], X[14, 2, 15, 1], X[17, 13, 18, 14],
X[23, 29, 24, 28], X[27, 7, 28, 8], X[24, 13, 25, 12], X[8, 12, 9, 11],
X[3, 16, 4, 1], X[32, 5, 17, 4], X[19, 15, 20, 16], X[20, 31, 21, 32],
X[25, 5, 26, 6], X[9, 6, 10, 7], X[26, 21, 27, 22], X[22, 11, 23, 10]
];

Hm. Regina seems to eat it without complaining. It returns the following as Jones polynomial: 511 - 1/T^17 + 7/T^16 - 30/T^15 + 93/T^14 - 230/T^13 + 479/T^12 - 860/T^11 + 1362/T^10 - 1926/T^9 + 2452/T^8 - 2833/T^7 + 2979/T^6 -  2857/T^5 + 2496/T^4 - 1978/T^3 + 1415/T^2 - 904/T - 250 T + 103 T^2 -   34 T^3 + 8 T^4 - T^5. Does this make sense?

@HenrikSchumacher It's worrying because Mathematica with KnotTheory gave a different polynomial entirely.

@HenrikSchumacher Can you try this one? It should give the same as the two component unlink, I think. K = PD[
X[31, 6, 32, 7], X[27, 32, 28, 17], X[2, 6, 3, 5], X[28, 2, 29, 1],
X[7, 4, 8, 5], X[29, 8, 30, 9], X[26, 4, 27, 3], X[30, 26, 31, 25],
X[17, 22, 18, 23], X[18, 12, 19, 11], X[21, 16, 22, 1], X[12, 16, 13, 15],
X[20, 10, 21, 9], X[13, 10, 14, 11], X[24, 20, 25, 19], X[23, 14, 24, 15]
];

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
